# web2py - routes.py not redirecting

Tags: python, silverlight, web2py

I'm writing simple app in web2py. I would like to use Silverlight as frontend. Web2py needs to expose some files at top level. For example, Silverlight application requests `http://127.0.0.1:8000/crossdomain.xml`. I created routes.py file in web2py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

routes_in=(
  ('.*:/crossdomain.xml','/app/static/crossdomain.xml'),
)
routes_out = (
)
```

When I start server and type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/crossdomain.xml in browser`, I get "invalid request" (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/static/crossdomain.xml` works). I'm a bit stuck. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**SOLVED**
I had to restart web2py server (web2py.exe on windows). I thought doing "stop server" and "start server" would be sufficient.

Thant you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried mapping just /crossdomain.xml?

Comment: Yes, it seems like web2py ignores routes.py file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the .*: is the problem; try leaving that off.

Comment: I solved the problem (and edited first post). Now it works both with ".*:" and without it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you click "Reload routes" in the admin panel it sorts things without having to restart the server.